# How do you replace the first and last line in Notepad++?

Tags: macros, notepad++

I'm trying to make a macro that does some replacements and in the end, deletes the first and the last lines in the document, but I've hit a dead end. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single regular expression replace can do this.

To delete the first and last lines: Select **Dot matches newline**, select **Wrap around** and set the **Find what** to be

```
\`[^\r\n]*[\r\n]+(.*[\r\n]+)[^\r\n]+[\r\n]*\'
```

Set the replace with to be

```
\1
```

My testing has sometimes required **Find next** to be pressed twice. The first find, for some unknown reason, only matches from somewhere in the middle of the buffer to the end.

The regular expression is interpreted as follows:

```
\`              Start of buffer
[^\r\n]*        First line, zero or more characters
[\r\n]+         Line separator
(.*[\r\n]+)     Central part of buffer
[^\r\n]+        Line separator before the last line
[\r\n]*         Optional line separators at end of buffer
\'              End of buffer
```

The question does not state how to handle the second line of the file being empty. The above with `[\r\n]+` will delete any blank lines after the first line. Similarly, the handing of empty lines near end of buffer may not be exactly as wanted. Changing both `[\r\n]+` to `\R` might be a stricter interpretation of what is wanted.

For the general case of modifying the first and last lines set the **Find what** to be:

```
\`([^\r\n]*)([\r\n]+.*[\r\n]+)([^\r\n]+)([\r\n]*)\'
```

Set the replace with to be

```
First \1 First\r\n\r\n\2\r\n\r\nLast \3 Last\4
```

Tested with Notepad++ version 6.7.8.2

Answer (score 0):

While the macro is recording press these keys...

```
Ctrl+Home
Shift+Down
Backspace
Ctrl+End
Shift+Home
Backspace
Backspace
```

That will delete the first and last lines of the document.